# Cascode MOSFETs for high voltage

Tags: flyback

In this circuit, the HV+ point ranges from 100 to 1200 VDC. The two MOSFETs are rated at 800V, which makes 1.6kV breakdown. D7/D8 are 300V each, so they have a clamping voltage of 600V. My question is:

If R7 is "large" there is no low impedance path to turn on or off Q1 so that turn off would happen very slowly which might be an issue for Q2, as I could get larger voltages on it.

If R7 is small (near zero), when Q2 turns off it would turn off Q1 quickly but the voltage at the Q1/Q2 connection is somewhat unpredictable. I want to get C5/C6 from almost zero volts when the FETs are on back up to half of HV+.  The only path to charge C5/C6 is through R4/R5/R6.  That will take a long time so Q1 might see most of the voltage for a while.

So is there actually a moment when a FET could see a voltage bigger than it can handle? At the end, the purpose of the cascode is to increase breakdown voltage of the main switch.

[image]

Comment: I think your circuit is going to have problems .If you put in some approx component values then answers will be more forthcoming

Comment: I'm using this reference design but with another controller: http://www.ti.com/lit/df/tidrlf7/tidrlf7.pdf

Comment: This is where you use a simulator. Have you thought about this?

Answer (score 1):

I may misunderstand what you may be asking, but "I want to get C5/C6 from almost zero volts when the FETs are on back up to half of HV+." may indicate that you believe C5/C6 are discharged when the FETs, Q1 and Q2, are turned on.  This is not the case.  Also, just in case HV+, or in other words the bus voltage from the rectified AC lines, is not the highest voltage that Q1 and Q2 will experience.  Note that is a flyback design so the maximum voltage that Q1 and Q2 will experience is a little more than HV+ plus the voltage drop of D13.  I also second the response from Autistic, values are helpful particularly the MOSFETs you would like to use.

Comment: I want to use two 800V mosfets like IPD80R2K0P7.

Comment: The voltage at the source of Q1 and drain of Q2 is not unpredictable.  This is because of D9 and D8 + D7.  In short, the drain of Q2 will never exceed much above the clamping voltage of D8 + D7.  This also means that with 300V TVS devices at D8 and D7 the drain source voltage across Q2 in its off state will be something a little above 600V which means that device has 200V of margin built in.  However IF the bus voltage is 1200V, as you state, and D13 is 100V, as it is in the reference design provided, the maximum drain source across Q1 would be 700V.  This leaves 100V margin on Q2.

Comment: I would trust TI and their reference design but it it were me I'd like to see a bit more margin in the breakdown characteristics of the MOSFETs and find something with a breakdown rating of 900V to 1000V.   Also keep both MOSFETs the same, as this would likely help with voltage sharing as the devices turn off.  Lastly, try to keep the gate input capacitance and gate charge characteristics as close to those in the reference design.  This might be tough though as a higher breakdown rating will likely mean the other MOSFET characteristics will not be a good as those in the reference design.

Comment: Thank you. I could get 950 FETs. I just have to be careful on the gate characteristics. I was wondering if I ever need C7 (in the picture above), it serves to slow down Q1 turn on as these FET usually have very low capacitance. I'm trying to follow this reference design as much as I can, even though I have to modify the transformer for my desired output, and I'm stuck at deciding at new D13 and the new reflected flyback voltage.

Comment: Also see that I'm using a UCC28711 instead of the LM5020. Need to check if this is OK.

Comment: Did you mean a margin of 100V on Q1, not Q2, right?

Comment: Oops, yes, and sorry I had one other error.  As I though about things more, C5 and C6 do get discharged when Q2 turns on (they are discharged through R7 and D9).

Comment: Also keep C7 but you may have to adjust the nominal capacitance of the device to suit the needs of the circuit (you may have to adjust it once you have produced a board).  C2 helps to protect the gate of Q1 against over-voltage and high frequency noise and the parasitic inductance and capacitance of the PCB tracing may dictate a new value selection for C2 once a prototype assembly is produced.

Answer (score 0):

Back in 1980 I designed a product that used a string of MOSFETs to handle 1 kV. Motorola published my circuit in a booklet on MOSFET applications. But that was a time when MOSFETs had at most 250 V rating. Since then, we have been blessed with a wide choice of high voltage MOSFETs, so ugly workarounds are no longer necessary. Just buy a high-voltage MOSFET: https://www.digikey.ca/short/n9c45pvh